# Vimeo API switch to new video

Tags: api, vimeo

I'm trying to get the vimeo universal player to play a new video in its iframe.

I don't want to initialise a complete new iframe each time I switch to a new video.

Is there a best practise to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your embed code is this:

```
<iframe id="vimeo_vid" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

then you could reload the frame using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  function loadit() {
    var loc = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/NEW_VID_ID";
    var iframe = $('#vimeo_vid');
    $(iframe).attr('src', loc);
  }
</script>
```

Call that function to change the content, like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadit()">Change Content</button>
```